# Invert open voice chords

Tags: piano, chords, learning, jazz, chord-inversions

when playing open voiced chords, do I still want to invert them so they fit each other? Or isn't open voiced chords as common to invert?

And when I play chords with my right hand, and bass note with left. Do I invert the bass as well when I invert my right hand chords? Or do I not to that, and moving big steps with bass is ok?

Edit: I'm talking about jazz piano here. Say I play a 2 5 1 progression inverted, to make smaller jump. Do I then go  d g c with my left hand playing the bass?

Comment: An inversion means a note other than the root note is in the bass, if you are ‘inverting’ the right hand but leaving the left unchanged thats just a different voicing, NOT an inversion. That said, you can do this as much as you want to get the desired effect. As you’ve noticed, if you invert a chord (including the left hand) you can get smoother, smaller jumps in the bass, and in jazz piano this is very heavily used. Note when playing with a band, especially a bass player, lots of listening is required to hear what each other is doing so as not to clash etc!

Answer (score 4):

Close and open voicings of chords are separate from inversions. One can have a close-voiced chord in root position, first inversion, etc., and one can also have an open-voiced chord in root position, first inversion, etc.

The inversion of a chord is determined solely by the lowest note, which on piano includes both hands. Imagine playing a low G in the left hand and G-B-D in the right hand. Changing only the low G to, say, a low D, and changing nothing in the right hand, produces a G major chord in second inversion.

The voicing can be changed in one or both hands, and it remains the lowest pitch that determines the inversion.

Given the example of a 2-5-1 progression, if the left hand is playing 2, 5, 1, then all of the chords are by definition in root position no matter what configuration of those chords the right hand is playing. The right hand can play whatever it likes — small jumps, big jumps, combinations of small and big jumps, notes close or open — according to the desired sound or ease of playing.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** Think about voice leading rather than whether or not you "need" to invert chords

> do I still want to invert them so they fit each other?

let's dive a little bit deeper into this. What you are describing in more technical terms is voice leading. We do often invert chords to facilitate good voice leading, however instead of thinking "Do I need to invert the chords" you should be thinking more along the lines of "How can I make good voice leading". In general if you avoid parallel fourths, fifths and avoid crossing your voices it will sound pretty good. (Sometimes you want to break those rules on purpose but that is just a baseline). So the question

> And when I play chords with my right hand, and bass note with left. Do I invert the bass as well when I invert my right hand chords? Or do I not to that, and moving big steps with bass is ok?

all comes back to voice leading. If you can arrange your open right hand voicings in such a way that your base isn't creating parallel fifths and fourths with something in your left hand then yeah go ahead and leave them in root inversion if you want. (Or if you think that it is more important to have them in root inversion then worrying about some really distant parallel fourths and fifths for your particular application). The problem with leaving all chords in root inversion when they are close together is not really the "big steps" per say it's more the crossing of voices that occurs along with the parallel fifths and fourths. So as you get more and more open you have more and more options without crossing or making parallel fourths/fifths. As a general rule, if you do the **exact** same voicing for 2 subsequent chords then you are almost certainly going to break some voice leading rules. When we use closed voicings the only way we can "rearrange" the notes is by inverting which is why to make good voice leading you have to invert constantly. As the notes get more spread apart we can instead of inverting switch which notes we choose to include between subsequent voicings and this can serve the same purpose.

I hope this helps (:

Answer (score 1):

Convention says that *inversions* are labelled by which note is lowest. With root lowest, it's called root position, with ^3 at the bottom, it's 1st inversion, with ^5, it's 2nd inversion. And so on. It keeps things simple, and on piano, it's more often (read always!) the bass note which dictates, regardless of the upper notes played.

You're talking about *voicing*, which is the changing of position of any/all the notes of a chord - could be *close* - all notes as close as possible, could be *open* - notes anywhere you like.

As with so much music, you as the player can play what and where you like. It often does sound more solid - 'better' - playing chords in root position, but that only means playing the root note with l.h. Obviously, you can voice the r.h. chord how you wish. But, you may decide, for example, on 2 bars of C, to play bass C in the 1st, and bass E in the second, which then prepares the ear for a bass F for the next bar on F.